# Questions about eigen vectors calculation in eignfaces

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I am calculating the eigen vectors from a set of M grayscale faces images and I am using two methods. I would expect to get the same results but calculation gave me the different outcomes.

Suppose I have been given the following 2 images, each has only 10 pixels.
$
M=
\left[
{
\begin{array}{cc}
2.5 & 2.4\\
0.5 & 0.7\\
2.2 & 2.9\\
1.9 & 2.2\\
3.1 & 3.0\\
2.3 & 2.7\\
2.0 & 1.6\\
1.0 & 1.1\\
1.5 & 1.6\\
1.1 & 0.9
\end{array}
}
\right]
$

Subtracted Mean from $M$ to get Matrix
$
\bar{M}=
\left[
{
\begin{array}{cc}
0.6900 & 0.4900 \\
-1.3100 & -1.2100 \\ 
0.3900 & 0.9900 \\
0.0900 & 0.2900 \\
1.2900 & 1.0900 \\
0.4900 & 0.7900 \\
0.1900 & -0.3100 \\ 
-0.8100 & -0.8100 \\
-0.3100 & -0.3100 \\
-0.7100 & -1.0100 
\end{array}
}
\right]
$

Obtain a covariance matrix \

\begin{eqnarray}
C = \bar{M}\bar{M}^{T}= \\
\left[
{
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
0.0796 & -0.1663 & 0.0838 & 0.0227 & 0.1582 & 0.0806 & -0.0023 & -0.1062 & -0.0406 & -0.1094 \\ 
-0.1663 & 0.3534 & -0.1899 & -0.0521 & -0.3343 & -0.1775 & 0.0140 &  0.2268 & 0.0868 & 0.2391 \\ 
0.0838 & -0.1899 & 0.1258 & 0.0358 & 0.1758 & 0.1081 & -0.0259 & -0.1242 & -0.0475 & -0.1419 \\
0.0227 & -0.0521 & 0.0358 & 0.0102 & 0.0480 & 0.0304 & -0.0081 & -0.0342 & -0.0131 & -0.0396 \\
0.1582 & -0.3343 & 0.1758 & 0.0480 & 0.3169 & 0.1659 & -0.0103 & -0.2142 & -0.0820 & -0.2241 \\ 
0.0806 & -0.1775 & 0.1081 & 0.0304 & 0.1659 & 0.0960 & -0.0169 & -0.1152 & -0.0441 & -0.1273 \\ 
-0.0023 & 0.0140 & -0.0259 & -0.0081 & -0.0103 & -0.0169 & 0.0147 & 0.0108 & 0.0041 & 0.0198 \\
-0.1062 & 0.2268 & -0.1242 & -0.0342 & -0.2142 & -0.1152 & 0.0108 & 0.1458 & 0.0558 & 0.1548 \\
-0.0406 & 0.0868 & -0.0475 & -0.0131 & -0.0820 & -0.0441 & 0.0041 & 0.0558 & 0.0214 & 0.0592 \\ 
-0.1094 & 0.2391 & -0.1419 & -0.0396 & -0.2241 & -0.1273 & 0.0198 &0.1548 & 0.0592 & 0.1694 
\end{array}
}
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

The first method to calculate the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix $C$ direct SVD on C

\begin{eqnarray}
E = \\
\left[
{
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
0.2436 & -0.2635 & 0.6008 & 0.0000 & 0.0000 & 0.0000 & 0.0000 & 0.0000
& 0.0000 & 0.7143 \\
-0.5229 & 0.2149 & -0.4587 & -0.1691 & 0.1472 & -0.0184 & 0.0423 & 0.0033 & 0.0603 & 0.6434 \\
0.2919 & 0.5783 & 0.0912 & 0.2501 & 0.3541 & 0.0279 & -0.0012 & -0.0504 
& 0.6160 & 0.0371 \\
0.0807 & 0.1962 & 0.0941 & -0.3549 & 0.3479 & -0.1255 & -0.6593 & -0.3834 & -0.3172 & -0.0343 \\ 
0.4930 & -0.3152 & -0.5340 & 0.2090 & 0.1815 & 0.0743 & -0.3509 & 0.3728 & -0.0313 & 0.1648 \\
0.2686 & 0.2637 & -0.1105 & 0.0079 & -0.2758 & -0.8420 & 0.1352 & 0.0770 & -0.1643 & 0.0987 \\
-0.0292 & -0.5263 & -0.1206 & -0.3010 & 0.0275 & -0.3391 & -0.0506 
& -0.3147 & 0.6268 & -0.0828 \\ 
-0.3367 & 0.0698 & 0.2719 & -0.0962 & -0.1719 & -0.1453 & -0.4934 
& 0.6566 & 0.2562 & -0.0882 \\ 
-0.1289 & 0.0267 & -0.0803 & 0.5531 & -0.5421 & 0.0516 & -0.4190 
& -0.4188 & 0.0902 & 0.1213 \\ 
-0.3600 & -0.2448 & 0.1382 & 0.5774 & 0.5465 & -0.3604 & 0.0257 & -0.0023 & -0.1475 & -0.0838 
\end{array}
}
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

The eigen values are 
\begin{eqnarray}
\Lambda = \\
\left[
{
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
1.2840 & 0.0491 & 0.0000 & 0.0000 & 0.0000 & 0.0000 & 0.0000 & 0.0000 & 0.0000 & 0.0000  
\end{array}
}
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

The second method reduces compleixty by calculating the inner product matrix $L=\bar{M}^{T}\bar{M}$ of the size 2×2. Then find it's eigenvectors $v_i$,i=1,2 of L (of the 2nd dimension).

\begin{eqnarray}
L = 
\left[
{
\begin{array}{cc}
0.6166 & 0.6154 \\
0.6154 & 0.7166 
\end{array}
}
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
V = 
\left[
{
\begin{array}{cc}
-0.6779 & 0.7352 \\ 
-0.7352 & -0.6779 
\end{array}
}
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda = 
\left[
{
\begin{array}{cc}
1.2840 & 0.0491 
\end{array}
}
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

Note that if $Lv_{i} = \lambda_{i}$, then

\begin{eqnarray}
\bar{M}Lv_{i} = \lambda_{i}\bar{M}v_{i} \\ 
\bar{M}\bar{M}^{T}v^{i} = \lambda_{i}\bar{M}v_{i} \\ 
C\bar{M}v_{i} = \lambda_{i}\bar{M}v_{i} 
\end{eqnarray}

and hence $u_i=\bar{M}v_i$ and $\lambda_{i}$ are respectively the 2 eigenvectors (of 10-th dimension) and eigenvalues of C. After normalizing $u_i$, such that $|u_i|=1$

\begin{eqnarray}
U = 
\left[
{
\begin{array}{cc}
-0.2436 & 0.2635 \\
0.5229 & -0.2149 \\ 
-0.2919 & -0.5783 \\ 
-0.0807 & -0.1962 \\  
-0.4930 & 0.3152 \\
-0.2686 & -0.2637 \\ 
0.0292 & 0.5263 \\
0.3367 & -0.0698 \\ 
0.1289 & -0.0267 \\ 
0.3600 & 0.2448  
\end{array}
}
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

The two eigen vector $U$ calculated in the second method is different to the two dominant eigen vectors calcualted in the first method by multiplying (-1).

Could someone explain to me what causes the difference? Is my calculation wrong or the result meant to be different by sign?

Many Thanks in advance.